# Azure maps POI search returns at max 100 TOTAL RESULTS

Tags: azure-maps

Search For eg search query - Hospital Country set- IN. total results found are <=100.if you send the request again the number of total results change. This has started happening recently and was working fine a couple weeks back.

The below result is definitely incorrect as the totalResults should be in thousands

eq query

[https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/poi/json?subscription-key={Your](https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/poi/json?subscription-key=%7BYour) key here}&api-version=1.0&limit=100&ofs=0&countrySet=IN&query=hospital&maxfuzzylevel=3&minfuzzylevel=1

summary
"summary": {
"query": "hospital",
"queryType": "NON_NEAR",
"queryTime": 374,
"numResults": 95,
"offset": 0,
"totalResults": 95,
"fuzzyLevel": 1
},

Expected totalResults to be returned in 1000s across India

Comment: Do see any official documentation on the limits?

Comment: The documentation says max 100 records will be returned in 1 request, but every request does show how many total results were found. So let's say I look for hospitals in India, Total can be 10000, but at 1 go it will give me max 100. Currently whatever we search in which ever geography results are always less than 100